# "Relay fee" error when sending funds from one account to another

Tags: transaction-fees, mempool, sending

I have a problem with bitcoin in sending payments from one user to another user. When I try to send, I get the error `txfee cannot be less than min relay tx fee (0.00001000 BTC/kB)`.

Please help with possible solutions [image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase your transaction fee to meet the minimums required by the node you are connected to. If you use a fee below that, the node (and other nodes on the network) will refuse to broadcast your transactions, preventing them from reaching miners.

Comment: const calculateTxFee = async (input, output, confirmations) => {
    try {
        const fee = await client.estimateSmartFee(6);
        var txFee = (((input * 148 + output * 34 + 10) + 40) / 1024) * fee['feerate'];
        console.log("txfee-------->", txFee)
        return txFee;
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("error 4 ------", err);
        throw err;
    }
}



This is the node.js code which I have written , please suggest what else should I add ?